# Can't unwrap Optional.None error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

When the value is passed for UILabel the error appears :

> Can't unwrap Optional.None

source code:

```
@IBOutlet var rowLabel : UILabel

var row: String? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        println(row)
        rowLabel.text = row
    }
}
```

Also error appears in label in the template for UITable when I appropriate new meaning:

```
let myCell : Cell =  Cell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
myCell.myLabel.text = "(indexPath.row)"
```

Comment: is it a compile-time error?

Comment: no, runtime:Thread 1:EXC_BAD_instruction(code=EXC_1186_INVOP,  subcode=0x0)

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: You must unwrap your value with ! operator. Try "rowLabel.text = row!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use newValue in willSet block, and oldValue in didSet block

example:

```
class foo {
    var row: String? {
    willSet {
        println("will set value:")
        println(newValue)
    }

    didSet {
        println("did change value:")
        println(oldValue)
    }
    }
}

var bar = foo()

println("First time setter called")
bar.row = "First value"
println("Second time setter called")
bar.row = "Second value"
```

output:

```
First time setter called
will set value:
First value
did change value:
nil
Second time setter called
will set value:
Second value
did change value:
First value
```

Comment: willSet always returns nil

Comment: in viewDidLoad value is passed to willSet. Thanks a lot))

Answer (score 3):

`row` is an `Optional` and it can be `nil`, i.e. `Optional.None`, so you need to unwrap it before assignment.

If you don't, I guess the runtime will try to unwrap it anyway, but it will fail with that error whenever a `nil` value is encountered.

Something like this should be safe

```
if let r = row {
   rowLabel.text = r    
}
```

If `row` is `nil`, it will never be assigned.

Comment: value comes and I get into condition, so continues to fall on the text assignment

Comment: When you're inside the `then` branch of the `if` conditional, `r` is the unwrapped value of `row`. It explicitly avoids `r` to be `nil`.

Comment: This will help in the future, thank you, but the value is not nil and it continues to crash