# Issue calling swift completion handler closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function which takes a closure as a completion handler. It in turn calls a function that takes one as well. On completion, I want to take the return values from the first completion closure and call the second passing them in.

```
func saveUserToCloud(user: MBUser, completionHandler: (CKRecord, NSError) -> Void) {
    let userRecord = CKRecord(recordType: kMBUser)
    userRecord.setObject(user.nickname, forKey: kMBUserNickname)
    self.publicDb.saveRecord(userRecord, completionHandler: {record, error in completionHandler(record, error)})
    }
}
```

This func throws an exception:

> fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

```
func saveUserToCloud(user: MBUser, completionHandler: (CKRecord, NSError) -> Void) {
    let userRecord = CKRecord(recordType: kMBUser)
    userRecord.setObject(user.nickname, forKey: kMBUserNickname)
    // this line throws the exception:
    self.publicDb.saveRecord(userRecord, completionHandler: {record, error in completionHandler(record, error)})
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have a record, and no error in this case. I suppose it's trying to unwrap the error?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `user` the optional value in the call? I'd check if the `user` object is correct state-wise. **Edit:** _perhaps check this SO answer as well, seems to be a related issue:_ http://stackoverflow.com/a/24035639/250164

Answer (score 0):

your nickname property is probably an optional property in your MBUser object. You could make it non optional or if you know it's set in this function enforce it with:

```
userRecord.setObject(user.nickname!, forKey: kMBUserNickname)
```

If nickname is nil then you will get the error here
I don't think the problem is your completionHandler